# Where is Git Repository in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: windows, git, aptana

I am trying to use SmartGit as a GUI to manage local and remote Git repositories.

I do all of my local coding / edits in Aptana Studio 3 and use the Git version control that is installed with all of the defaults in that IDE.

What I want to be able to do is to import / browse the Git local repo that Aptana is making by using SmartGit and to use SmartGit to upload / browse / merge with a BitBucket Git repo.

But I cannot find the "local" (Aptana) repo files...

Crazy question and I have done all kinds of Google searches, SO searches,  and file system searches trying every trick I can think of to find "needle" in "haystack" but all to no avail....where is the repo folder on Windows 7 Aptana Studio 3?

Comment: Which repo? It's wherever you put it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the location of the bundles, by default they are located in:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Aptana Rubles
```

The Aptana installation itself is located at:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Aptana Studio 3
```